# Filtering nulls after an outer join in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I'm currently trying to figure out how to do a filter with a left join involving nulls. Here's a simplified
version of the schema I'm working on:

```
CREATE TABLE bookclubs (
    bookclub_id UUID NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE books (
    bookclub_id UUID NOT NULL,
    book_id UUID NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE books ADD CONSTRAINT books_pk PRIMARY KEY(bookclub_id, book_id);
ALTER TABLE books ADD CONSTRAINT book_to_bookclub FOREIGN KEY(bookclub_id)
  REFERENCES bookclubs(bookclub_id) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE;
CREATE INDEX books_bookclub_index ON books (bookclub_id);

CREATE TABLE book_reviews (
    bookclub_id UUID NOT NULL,
    book_id UUID NOT NULL,
    reviewer_id TEXT NOT NULL,
    rating int8 NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE book_reviews ADD CONSTRAINT book_reviews_pk PRIMARY KEY(bookclub_id, book_id, reviewer_id);
ALTER TABLE book_reviews ADD CONSTRAINT book_review_to_book FOREIGN KEY(bookclub_id,book_id)
  REFERENCES books(bookclub_id,book_id) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE;
CREATE INDEX book_review_to_book_index ON book_reviews ( bookclub_id, book_id);
CREATE INDEX book_review_by_reviewer ON book_reviews ( bookclub_id, reviewer_id, rating);
```

I want a query that for a given `bookclub_id` and `reviewer_id`, returns me all the books that they've rated >= 3, or that they haven't rated. Books they haven't rated have no entry in the `book_reviews` table, which isn't something I can do anything about. `rating` is actually an enum if that's relevant, but I don't think it is.

My first attempt at doing the obvious thing failed:

```
SELECT *
FROM   books
       LEFT OUTER JOIN book_reviews
                    ON ( ( ( books.bookclub_id = book_reviews.bookclub_id )
                           AND ( books.book_id = book_reviews.book_id ) )
                         AND ( book_reviews.reviewer_id = 'alice' ) )
WHERE  books.bookclub_id = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
       AND book_reviews.rating != 1
       AND book_reviews.rating != 2;
```

This drops books that don't have reviews from the user, which makes some sense once I think about how the `WHERE` conditions are actually implemented. Here's the query plan

```
Nested Loop  (cost=0.30..16.39 rows=1 width=104)
  ->  Index Scan using book_reviews_pk on book_reviews  (cost=0.15..8.21 rows=1 width=72)
        Index Cond: ((bookclub_id = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'::uuid) AND (reviewer_id = 'alice'::text))
        Filter: ((rating <> 1) AND (rating <> 2))
  ->  Index Only Scan using books_pk on books  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=32)
        Index Cond: ((bookclub_id = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'::uuid) AND (book_id = book_reviews.book_id))
```

So I added an explicit check for null:

```
SELECT *
FROM   books
       LEFT OUTER JOIN book_reviews
                    ON ( ( ( books.bookclub_id = book_reviews.bookclub_id )
                           AND ( books.book_id = book_reviews.book_id ) )
                         AND ( book_reviews.reviewer_id = 'alice' ) )
WHERE  books.bookclub_id = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
       AND book_reviews.rating IS NULL
       OR ( book_reviews.rating != 1
          AND book_reviews.rating != 2);
```

This returns the correct results, but appears to be horribly inefficient, and grinds the db to a halt. Here's the query plan

```
Hash Left Join  (cost=18.75..52.56 rows=1346 width=104)
   Hash Cond: ((books.bookclub_id = book_reviews.bookclub_id) AND (books.book_id = book_reviews.book_id))
   Filter: (((books.bookclub_id = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'::uuid) AND (book_reviews.rating IS NULL)) OR ((book_reviews.rating <> 1) AND (book_reviews.rating <> 2)))
   ->  Seq Scan on books  (cost=0.00..23.60 rows=1360 width=32)
   ->  Hash  (cost=18.69..18.69 rows=4 width=72)
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on book_reviews  (cost=10.23..18.69 rows=4 width=72)
               Recheck Cond: (reviewer_id = 'alice'::text)
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on book_review_by_reviewer  (cost=0.00..10.22 rows=4 width=0)
                     Index Cond: (reviewer_id = 'alice'::text)
```

I'm no expert on interpreting these things, but that `Filter` moving to the outside seems bad. Is there an efficient way to structure the query such that I can get the result I want? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Move the filter to the join condition:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    books
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    book_reviews ON 
        books.bookclub_id = book_reviews.bookclub_id 
        AND books.book_id = book_reviews.book_id 
        AND book_reviews.reviewer_id = 'alice'
        AND book_reviews.rating != 1
        AND book_reviews.rating != 2
WHERE books.bookclub_id = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
```

or a bit shorter:

```
AND book_reviews.rating not in (1, 2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't seem to be working quite right. I still get rows that should be filtered out with nulls for the review stuff
https://gist.github.com/drapp/0e9b09fe97f99a27fa1dde2683df7316

Comment: @DouglasRapp I think now I understand the problem. I will not have the time today but I will try it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I believe we figured it out. We were missing a set of parens in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM   books
       LEFT OUTER JOIN book_reviews
                    ON ( ( ( books.bookclub_id = book_reviews.bookclub_id )
                           AND ( books.book_id = book_reviews.book_id ) )
                         AND ( book_reviews.reviewer_id = 'alice' ) )
WHERE  books.bookclub_id = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
       AND ( book_reviews.rating IS NULL
            OR ( book_reviews.rating != 1
            AND book_reviews.rating != 2) );
```

Without that the boolean logic associates wrong. This query returns the right result and has a sane query plan, so it looks like that was the entire issue. Thanks for looking.